# How to use generics in an arbitrary abstraction layer?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

[Sample Project Here](https://github.com/evandelaney/StackOverflow-34777632)

#### Abstract

I'm trying to understand how to refactor code and using Swift generics. I'm able to identify a common implementation across several conceptually similar types, but I am having difficulty because the layers that code builds upon is not generic.

#### Background

Here's my understanding of some the concepts I think I want to leverage.

*Protocols*

Useful for declaring an interface and having many "concrete" implementations of that interface. This allows you to swap out implementations at runtime.

*Generics*

Useful when an implementation is the same or similar, but the types differ. Seems like the canonical example is swapping two values or `map`.

#### Problem

I have a client class (`APIClient`) that is responsible for creating URL requests. The client only knows about primary data types (integers, strings, arrays, JSON, etc). Above the client class sit several classes that abstract the domain objects (`FruitDownloader`, `TrafficDownloader`, and `WildlifeDownloader`). This class knows how to unpack primary data types from a domain type and call into the correct client method. This class uses mapper classes (`FruitMapper`, `TrafficMapper`, and `WildlifeMapper`) to construct domain objects from JSON.

The implementations of the `...Dowloader` classes is very similar:

```
class FruitDownloader {

    init(client: APIClient, mapper: FruitMapper)
    {
        self.client = client
        self.mapper = mapper
    }

    func downloadFruit(location: Location, season: Season, successHandler: (([ Fruit ]) -> Void)?, failureHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)?)
    {
        client.getFruitsForRegionIdentifier(location.identifier,
            seasonIdentifier: season.identifier,
            successHandler: { objectNotation in
                if let instances = objectNotation["fruit_data"] as? [ ObjectNotation ] {
                    do {
                        let fruits = try instances.map(self.mapper.fruit)
                        successHandler?(fruits)
                    }
                    catch let error as NSError {
                        failureHandler?(error)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    failureHandler?(NSError(domain: "com.fruit.downloader", code: 1000, userInfo: nil))
                }
            },
            failureHandler: failureHandler)
    }

    private let client: APIClient
    private let mapper: FruitMapper
}

class TrafficDownloader {

    init(client: APIClient, mapper: TrafficMapper)
    {
        self.client = client
        self.mapper = mapper
    }

    func downloadTraffic(location: Location, season: Season, successHandler: (([ Traffic ]) -> Void)?, failureHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)?)
    {
        client.getHistoricalTrafficReportForRegionIdentifier(location.identifier,
            seasonIdentifier: season.identifier,
            successHandler: { objectNotation in
                if let instances = objectNotation["data"] as? [ ObjectNotation ] {
                    do {
                        let trafficReport = try instances.map(self.mapper.traffic)
                        successHandler?(trafficReport)
                    }
                    catch let error as NSError {
                        failureHandler?(error)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    failureHandler?(NSError(domain: "com.traffic.downloader", code: 1000, userInfo: nil))
                }
            },
            failureHandler: failureHandler)
    }

    private let client: APIClient
    private let mapper: TrafficMapper
}

class WildlifeDownloader {

    init(client: APIClient, mapper: WildlifeMapper)
    {
        self.client = client
        self.mapper = mapper
    }

    func downloadWildlife(location: Location, successHandler: (([ Wildlife ]) -> Void)?, failureHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)?)
    {
        client.getWildlifeForRegionIdentifier(location.identifier,
            successHandler: { objectNotation in
                if let instances = objectNotation["content"] as? [ ObjectNotation ] {
                    do {
                        let wildlife = try instances.map(self.mapper.wildlife)
                        successHandler?(wildlife)
                    }
                    catch let error as NSError {
                        failureHandler?(error)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    failureHandler?(NSError(domain: "com.wildlife.downloader", code: 1000, userInfo: nil))
                }
            },
            failureHandler: failureHandler)
    }

    private let client: APIClient
    private let mapper: WildlifeMapper
}
```

**Okay, this looks ripe for a `Downloader` class that's generic over `T`. Alright, so there are some immediate concerns:**

1. Each downloader class uses a domain specific mapper.
2. Each downloader has to grope through the `ObjectNotation` for a special key.
3. The arguments of the client methods varies just a little bit.
4. Each downloader calls into a specific client method.

Let's handle these in turn:

#### 1: Protocol with an associated type

Instead of downloader using a specific mapper, let's have it use something that is the type `Mappable`. The mappable protocol needs to be generic for many different types, so we can accomplish this by using an associated type.

```
protocol MapperType {
    typealias ObjectType
    func object(objectNotation: ObjectNotation) throws -> ObjectType
}
```

#### 2: Object Notation Manipulation

Meh, I'm not really sure of a good way to handle this. But, I could declare another protocol `Mappable` and have my model objects conform.

```
protocol Mappable {
    static func objectNotationRoot() -> String
}
```

#### 3: Downloader arguments

Some downloaders take a `Location` and a `Season` the other take just a `Location`. The generic downloader can take both and throw away the `Season` instance when it isn't needed, but this feels like leaky abstraction.

#### 4: Calling different methods based on type

Okay, now I'm really stuck. How do I call down into client? It feels really gross to inspect `T` for its type, and make a decision based on that. The type information is in downloader and client doesn't take or use this information. Should I be thinking that I need to wedge something between these layers?

Here's what my half-baked generic downloader looks like:

```
class Downloader<T: Mappable, U: MapperType where U.ObjectType == T> {

    init(client: APIClient, mapper: U)
    {
        self.client = client
        self.mapper = mapper
    }

    func download(location: Location, season: Season, successHandler: (([ T ]) -> Void)?, failureHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)?)
    {
        client._________(location.identifier,
            seasonIdentifier: season.identifier,
            successHandler: { objectNotation in
                if let instances = objectNotation[T.objectNotationRoot()] as? [ ObjectNotation ] {
                    do {
                        let objects = try instances.map(self.mapper.object)
                        successHandler?(objects)
                    }
                    catch let error as NSError {
                        failureHandler?(error)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    failureHandler?(NSError(domain: "com.fruit.downloader", code: 1000, userInfo: nil))
                }
            },
            failureHandler: failureHandler)
    }

    private let client: APIClient
    private let mapper: U
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way, but you really don't need all the protocols. A single struct is plenty, along with some functions and "one strange trick."

The "one strange trick" is that methods are really curried functions that take their object as the first parameter. So given this:

```
struct Foo {
    func bar() {}
}
```

there is a function, `Foo.bar(self: Foo)` that returns a function `() -> Void`. That may not make perfect sense yet, but we'll use it later.

First, our `Downloader` (as currently designed) needs four things: a client, a way to fetch stuff, a way to find the top of the tree, and a way to map what you find into objects. So we make that:

```
struct Downloader<ObjectType> {
    let client: APIClient
    let fetcher: Fetcher
    let rootKey: String
    let mapper: (ObjectNotation) throws -> ObjectType
}
```

For convenience, I've created the following typealias because it's so enormous:

```
typealias Fetcher = (APIClient) -> (locationIdentifier: String, seasonIdentifier: Int, successHandler: ((ObjectNotation) -> Void)?, failureHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)?) -> NSURL
```

What kind of function has that type? Well, `APIClient.getFruitsForRegionIdentifier` has that type (that's where I copied it from). So we'll be able to pass that as the fetcher.

With those in place `download` is pretty simple:

```
func download(location: Location, season: Season, successHandler: (([ ObjectType ]) -> Void)?, failureHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)?) {
    fetcher(client)(
        locationIdentifier: location.identifier,
        seasonIdentifier: season.identifier,
        successHandler: self.successWrapper(successHandler: successHandler, failureHandler: failureHandler),
        failureHandler: failureHandler)
}
```

Just to make it a little easier to read, I hauled out that success block. It takes a successHandler and a failureHandler and returns a new success handler.

```
func successWrapper(successHandler successHandler: (([ ObjectType ]) -> Void)?, failureHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)?)
    -> ((objectNotation: ObjectNotation) -> Void) {
        return { objectNotation in
            if let instances = objectNotation[self.rootKey] as? [ ObjectNotation ] {
                do {
                    let objects = try instances.map(self.mapper)
                    successHandler?(objects)
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    failureHandler?(error)
                }
            }
            else {
                failureHandler?(NSError(domain: "com.fruit.downloader", code: 1000, userInfo: nil))
            }
        }
}
```

OK, lots of stuff there. How do we use it? Well, we can create a Fruit downloader like this:

```
let fruitDownloader = Downloader<Fruit>(
    client: APIClient(baseURL: NSURL()),
    fetcher: APIClient.getFruitsForRegionIdentifier, // <- That curried function we talked about
    rootKey: "fruit_data",
    mapper: simpleMapper("fruit")
)
```

where `simppleMapper` is just a helper:

```
extension String: ErrorType {} // For sloppy errors

func simpleMapper<T>(key: String) -> (ObjectNotation) throws -> T {
    return { objectNotation in
        guard let value = objectNotation[key] as? T else {
            throw "Could not!" // FIXME
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

And we're pretty much done. The key here, all over the place, is higher-order functions. Functions that take functions and return us new functions.

With higher-order functions, you could probably simplify even more of this. Looking at `APIClient`, it isn't clear why we really need all these different methods. It kind of looks like the only thing that varies is the URL template. Maybe we just need a function for that and attach it to the Downloader.

You might notice that we don't really even need a `Downloader` struct. It just wraps a single method and doesn't even have any state (which is why it certainly shouldn't be a class). We could have built it as just a function that returns the download function (like `simpleMapper` does). There are some benefits to structs (you can print out their properties in the debugger for instance), so I'm not saying you should get rid of all of them, but it's good to remember that you have options.

(I notice that Wildlife has a different function signature, missing `Season`. It's not clear if that's intentional. If it is, then you may have to make another layer of functions that throws away the season that's passed. But it shouldn't be complicated. Just think functions that return functions.)

[All the code together as a gist.](https://gist.github.com/rnapier/68086b402387a9f25ce0)